# How to end session for custom Alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am creating a custom skill for Alexa. I want to close the session on `AMAZON.StopIntent`. How can I achieve this with below code?

```
const ExitHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('bye!')
      .reprompt('bye!')
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Alexa ends the session when **shouldEndSession** flag is set to true in the response JSON.

```
... 
"shouldEndSession": true
...
```

In your response builder can you try with the helper function **withShouldEndSession(true)**

```
 return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('bye!')
      .withShouldEndSession(true)
      .getResponse();
```

Response builder helper functions are listed [here](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Response-Building.html)

Comment: You have no idea how much googling I had to do to find out .withShouldEndSession(true/false) exists.  Thank you

Answer (score 7):

In your code snippet you would end the session just by removing the reprompt line:

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
  .speak('bye!')
  .getResponse();
```

so the suggested solution below works but it's redundant:

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('bye!')
      .withShouldEndSession(true)
      .getResponse();
```

The code above is often used in the opposite scenario, when you want to keep the session open without a reprompt:

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('bye!')
      .withShouldEndSession(false)
      .getResponse();
```

Comment: How long are the session attributes maintained when .withShouldEndSession(false) flag is used?

Comment: Until the session times out. In a real device a few seconds, 8 secs if I remember correctly. In the simulator (Test tab on developer.amazon.com/alexa) a very long long time (basically it does not time out unless you're logged out of the page)

Comment: So practically what is the use of .withShouldEndSession(false) on a real device?

Comment: It's the only way to keep a session open allowing the device to listen for a new utterance without providing a reprompt. Basically you use it when you don't want to insist on getting an answer (via reprompt) but allowing the user to say something once