# Alexa Not Recognizing Custom Intent's Utterances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I created an Alexa 'fact' skill recently and I'm having trouble with the utterances. I created an intent then associated a few utterances with that intent. I did not include any intent slots. When I test my skill, I have to use the invocation name in order to bring back results from lambda. None of the sample utterances I created return results.

Comment: Can you share handler function of your custom intent

Comment: @CicilThomas I basically built my skill based on https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact only I changed the intent from Space Fact to Telling Jokes. My invocation name is "Telling Jokes", and I put "say something funny", "I'm not very happy" as my utterances. What I'm trying to do is that: if I tell Alexa one of these utterances, it will tell a joke. But so far it's not recognizing any of these utterances.

Comment: You have to open the skill and for that yo u have to use an invocation name. Once you open the skill, then if you keep the session alive you can use your utterances directly without invocation name.

Comment: @CicilThomas how to keep the session alive ?

Comment: @charany1 session is kept alive based on the property `"shouldEndSession"` in response. If you set to false, it will keep the session open for next 8 seconds. If you give a reprompt, it will again wait for another 8 seconds. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51174826/1574023).